# JIS X 0208 conversion: how to handle unified (merged) codepoints

Tags: java, character-encoding

I'm trying to convert Java characters to JIS X 0208 "x-JIS0208" encoding (or any compatible, like EUC-JP, but not Shift-JIS), but I want unified (merged) codepoints to be handled correctly.

For example, 高 is assigned to row 25 column 66 in [this JISX0208 chart](http://www.dennougedougakkai-ndd.org/pub/gutenberg/jisx0208-1990.gif), and a look-alike character 髙, while classified as an unassigned codepoint, is merged with the former. I quote from wikipedia: "both the form [ ] (高) and the less common form with a ladder-like construction (髙) are subsumed into the same code point".

I tried this in code the code below, and whatever encoding I try, I always get either an exception or the unassigned-character-placeholder `?` (either ASCII or full-width).

Is there a way, perhaps a different endoding or an entirely different way of converting, so both these characters return the same codepoint? Alternatively, is there an API to find such characters so I can merge them before converting?

```
static Charset      charset1    = Charset.forName("x-JIS0208");
static Charset      charset2    = Charset.forName("EUC-JP");
static Charset[]    charsets    = {charset1, charset2};

static CharBuffer   in          = CharBuffer.allocate(1);

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    CharsetEncoder[] encoders = new CharsetEncoder[charsets.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < charsets.length; i++)
        encoders[i] = charsets[i].newEncoder();

    char[] testChars = {'　', 'Ａ', '？', '亜', '唖', '蔭', '高', '髙'};

    for (char ch : testChars)
    {
        System.out.print("'" + ch + "'\t(" + Integer.toHexString(ch) + ")\t=");

        for (int i = 0; i < charsets.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("\t" + interpret(encode1(encoders[i], ch)));
            System.out.print("\t" + interpret(encode2(charsets[i], ch)));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

private static String interpret(int i)
{
    if (i == -1)
        return "excepti";
    if (i < 0x80)
        return "'" + (char)i + "'";
    return Integer.toHexString(i);
}

private static int encode1(CharsetEncoder encoder, char ch)
{
    in.rewind();
    in.put(ch);
    in.rewind();

    try
    {
        ByteBuffer out = encoder.encode(in);

        if (out.limit() == 1)
            return out.get(0) & 0xFF;
        return out.get(1) & 0xFF | (out.get(0) & 0xFF) << 8;
    }
    catch (CharacterCodingException e)
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

private static int encode2(Charset charset, char ch)
{
    in.rewind();
    in.put(ch);
    in.rewind();

    ByteBuffer out = charset.encode(in);

    if (out.limit() == 1)
        return out.get(0) & 0xFF;
    return out.get(1) & 0xFF | (out.get(0) & 0xFF) << 8;
}
```

The output:

```
'　' (3000)  =   2121    2121    a1a1    a1a1
'Ａ' (ff21)  =   2341    2341    a3c1    a3c1
'？' (ff1f)  =   2129    2129    a1a9    a1a9
'亜' (4e9c)  =   3021    3021    b0a1    b0a1
'唖' (5516)  =   3022    3022    b0a2    b0a2
'蔭' (852d)  =   307e    307e    b0fe    b0fe
'高' (9ad8)  =   3962    3962    b9e2    b9e2
'髙' (9ad9)  =   excepti 2129    excepti '?'
```

Note: I'm only interested in converting single characters, lots of them, not strings or streams, so I actually prefer a different method (if exists) that doesn't allocate a ByteBuffer every conversion.

Answer (score 1):

髙 is not contained in JIS X 0208, but is containd in Microsoft Windows code page 932 (MS932). This is a variant of Shift JIS encoding, and is a superset of JIS X 0208 charset.
You should use the name "Windows-31j" for MS932, like:

```
Charset.forName("Windows-31j");
```

rather than `Charset.forName("x-JIS0208");`.

### EDIT

The mapping table for some characters like  and 鋏 (scissors) is distributed from the government of Japan, like [National Tax Agency](http://www.houjin-bangou.nta.go.jp/download/) (see `JIS縮退マップ（Ver.1.0.0）`) .
But these mapping tables don't contain the character `髙`. I think this is because `髙` is not contained in JIS X 0208 nor JIS X 0213.

So, I think you will have to replace `髙` with `高` manually (with `String#replaceAll()`), or make your own custom `Charset` with `CharsetProvider`.

Comment: This converts the ladder-髙 to a valid codepoint, but a different one than 高. It only solves half my question.

Comment: I edited my answer. I think it is difficult to achieve it with Java-supported encodings.

Answer (score 0):

I only knew that in the spec "ARIB STD-B24" (for ISDB-T 1seg in JP), this character is coding with DRCS pattern data, from DRCS-1 to DRCS-15, and each set consists of 94
characters.